# There is a polygon in 2D space. Find its area

Tags: c#

There is a polygon in 2D space. Find its area. 
An array of numbers:

1. Positive integer n, the quantity of the polygon vertices.
2. Sequence of reals with n subsequences of two numbers, each subsequence contains the 2D coordinates of a vertex of the polygon.
   Output:

A real, the area of the polygon

What is wrong with my code?

Example:

Input:
3 1.0 0.0 0.0 2.0 -1.0 0.0 
Output:
2

class Program
    {

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        var numbers = input.Split(' ').Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToArray();

        var a = (int) numbers[0];

        double[] arr = numbers.Skip(1).Take(a).ToArray();

        double[,] coord = new double[2, a];

        for(int i = 0; i <= arr.Length/2; i++)
        {
            coord[0, i] = arr[i];
            coord[1, i] = arr[1+i];
        }

        double sum1 = 0;
        double sum2 = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < a - 1; i++)
        {
            sum1 += coord[0, i] * coord[1, i + 1];
            sum2 += coord[1, i] * coord[0, i + 1];
        }

        double area = Math.Abs((sum1 - sum2) / 2d);

        Console.Write(coord[0,2]);
        Console.ReadKey(); 

    }



}
```

Comment: Did you wrap around the array and multiply the xy of the last vertex with the yx of the first vertex?

Comment: No, how i can do it?

Comment: I'd use mod-by-array-length operation when indexing the array, and have the loop run to array.Length instead of Length-1. Also remember that `a` is equal to array length if you want to make the code simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of fixes, arr should collect all the numbers after length, remove Take() as:

```
double[] arr = numbers.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

and replace your first for loop with this:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i+=2)
{
  coord[0, j] = arr[i];
  coord[1, j] = arr[1 + i];
  j++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need your for loop to be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
        sum1 += coord[0, i] * coord[1, (i + 1)%a];
        sum2 += coord[1, i] * coord[0, (i + 1)%a];
}
```

Reason why is the formula for polygon area requires you to multiply the last vertex x by the first vertex y etc (wrap around the array end)

By making the loop run to `i<a` it will run one more time than your `i<a-1`, coord[..., i] is still within the array bounds  but `i+1` would be outside unless we mod it by the array length.. any number mod by x produces a result in the range 0 to x-1, so this mod operation keeps the index within the array bounds and wraps it round to 0 when it otherwise would have gone one past the end of the array. This way you multiply the last vertex i by the first vertex `(i+1)%a => 0`

For what it worth if this were my task I probably would have parsed to a list of System.Drawing.Point structs then they would have had .X and .Y properties and the code would have been more readable